# Magento2: What is the reason why I can't reindex in Production?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, reindex, production-mode

I wonder why Magento 2 disable reindex in Admin GUI area when production mode is enabled.

Every time our clients uploaded new catalog products from import, we need to reindex via command line. This isn't useful for us.

Can you tell us why the Magento team intentionally disabled this feature when in production? Or do I need to adjust any settings to make indexing available in GUI Admin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The indexing functionality is not only disable in production mode , but its not there in Magento 2.**

You can not  do reindexing from magento 2 backend admin ui , there is no option or settings to enable this because it is not there.

> if you have issue with the product import , you can do one solution like
>   set indexing on **UPDATE ON SAVE** mode , so every time when you 
>   import product or add product it will automatically do indexing
>   itself.

**You can also set cronjobs for the same , that will called on specific time schedule like if you have heavy rush of product import process then you can set cron jobs for 1 mins as well.**

Comment: Of course you can. Just do `php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Answer (score 2):

For indexing you have to setup cron, because if you run indexer manually it only index onetime and if you make any change on catalog level you have to reindex again.

to avoid this you have to setup cron-job to run it automatically :

As per [dev dcos](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html) :

```
This command reindexes one time only. To keep indexers up-to-date, you must set up a cron job.
```